# Can not access phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql

I tried to access phpMyAdmin but I get an error.

> Cannot connect: invalid settings.
>   phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

Comment: Can you access the MySQL server with the credentials you are trying to use in PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: I think that the phrase "You should check the host, username and password in your configuration " is a good clue to what might be the problem.

Comment: As Steve says. Check with your web host as to the format/type of credentials that are expected.

Answer (score 1):

Are you have start the phpmyadmin service ?
If you are using xampp, check the phpmyadmin configuration:

1. C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin
2. open and edit **config.inc.php** with your text editor

Look at this line:

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
```

In this configuration, the username is "root" and password is empty, hosted on 127.0.0.1